# Запрос нескольких строк, а не столбцов из dual

Tags: sql, oracle

Нужен аналог кода

```
SELECT 'Хочу' as TEXT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'упростить' as TEXT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'этот' as TEXT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'кода' as TEXT FROM DUAL
```

Что-то вроде:

```
SELECT X AS TEXT FROM DUAL WHERE X IN (
  'Хочу',
  'упростить',
  'этот',
  'код')
```

То есть вопрос в том, как одним запросом вытягивать из dual несколько значений?

Comment: `select 1,2,3 from dual`?

Comment: Это будет три столбца, а не три строки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select column_value as text
  from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('Хочу','упростить','этот','кода'))
```

Comment: ЕМНИП DBA должен запустить `{ORACLE_HOME}/rdbms/admin/catodci.sql` на сервере, чтобы создалась данная функция...

Answer (score 3):

Решений, как обычно, может быть чуть меньше, чем звёзд на небе. Вот ещё парочка для полноты:

```
select trim (column_value) as text 
from xmlTable ('"Хочу", "упростить", "этот", "код"');

select column_value as text 
from table (sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll ('Хочу', 'упростить', 'этот', 'код'));
```

Выведут:

```
TEXT       
----------
Хочу      
упростить 
этот      
код
```

Answer (score 2):

Во многих местах (всякие статьи да справки) вижу конструкции типа

```
WITH tablename (fieldname) AS (VALUES ('value 1'),
                                      ('value 2'),
--
                                      ('value N'))
```

или

```
FROM (VALUES ('value 1'),
             ('value 2'),
--
             ('value N')) tablename (fieldname)
```

применительно именно к Oracle. Но сам не использовал (да и нет у меня Oracle...).

**-= UPDATE =-**

[Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike) не поленился проверить на [livesql.oracle.com](https://livesql.oracle.com/) - увы, но конструкция не работает...

Comment: А эта дока точно относится к oracle database, а не например к oracle javadb, которая совершенно другая СУБД ?

Comment: @Mike Ну вот навскидку: [ссылка](http://datareview.info/article/8-sposobov-obedineniya-join-tablic-v-sql-chast-2/), там, где "Латеральное объединение", причём явно пишется, что сие в т.ч. и для Oracle. Насколько показанный там код работоспособен именно в Оракле - я фиг знает...

Comment: Ну в 11 не работает. 12c под руками нет. может чего и доделали, учитывая что lateral обсуждаемый в том же примере появился в 12c.

Comment: На https://livesql.oracle.com не работает, там аж 18c версия ...

Comment: @Mike Ну значит фигня написана... бывает.

Comment: @Akina Там не фигня, там пример с pg.

Comment: @0xdb Я вообще-то достаточно явно указал на текст "Давайте рассмотрим пример использования ключевого слова LATERAL в PostgreSQL / **Oracle**". Что показанный код - постгресса, я вижу. Но слово Oracle я тоже вижу.

Comment: @Akina Ну да, упомянули,что LATERAL поддерживается, а пример, который в Oracle работает,  дать по-видимому забыли.

Comment: @Akina, ЕМНИП DBA должен запустить {ORACLE_HOME}/rdbms/admin/catodci.sql на сервере, чтобы создалась функция `sys.odcivarchar2list`

Comment: @0xdb По-моему, Вы забыли, что собственно обсуждается. А обсуждается мой ответ - который совсем даже не про LATERAL...

Comment: @MaxU `sys.odcivarchar2list` - костыль. Достаточно того, что у неё достаточно жёсткое ограничение на количество аргументов...

Comment: @Akina Нет,  не забыл, я же про values в from в вашем ответе, который в Oracle  не поддерживается. Или я вас не правильно понял? Причём здесь lateral?